# How to enter holiday calender in Microsoft Project?

Tags: ms-project

I want to enter company holidays in the default working calender in Microsoft Project. 
But everytime I create new file, I have to re-enter holidays again.

Is there a way to save the holidays, so that when we create new projects, we don't have to define it every time?

Comment: Which version? 2007 or 2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Project 2003 and 2007, the only way I have been able to accomplish this is by changing the working calendar on a project, saving that project as a template, and then sharing the template.

Answer (score 0):

Open a current project or new project, change the project calendar and add the calendar to the global file. Saving it as a global file makes the calendar visible to all projects.
Steps to add calendar to global file
a) Go to Tools => Organizer
b) Select Calendar Tab and click Copy.